# Const data type cannot be assigned into a non-const data type

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to make a really simple string class with a copy constructor, the problem that i am having is that i am trying to send a data type/object as a constant but whenever i try to assign it to the same non-constant data, the compiler complains.

I don't get why would compiler complain, i am just trying to copy the data, i am not modify it.

Header

```
class MyString{
private:
    char* thestring;
    MyString* ms;
public:
    MyString();
    MyString(const char* str);
    MyString(const MyString& str);
    ~MyString();
    MyString& operator=(const char* str);
};
```

CPP

```
MyString::MyString(){
    thestring = '\0';
}

MyString::MyString(const MyString& str){
    ms = str;
}

MyString& MyString::operator=(const char* str){
    MyString* temp = new MyString();
    temp->thestring = str; 
    return temp;
}

MyString::MyString(const char* str){
}

MyString::~MyString(){
}
```

here are the erros:

> no suitable conversion function from "const MyString" to "MyString *"
>   exists 9
>
> a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type
>   "char *"  14
>
> a reference of type "MyString &" (not const-qualified) cannot be
>   initialized with a value of type "MyString *" 15
>
> 'MyString::operator=' : must return a value 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not need `ms` member in your class: it serves no purpose, and it is used only in your (incorrect) copy constructor. Remove `ms`, and rewrite the code as follows:

```
MyString::MyString(const MyString& str) {
    thestring = strdup(str.thestring);
}
```

Note that now your code violates the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29): once you add a copy constructor, you also need a matching assignment operator and a destructor:

```
MyString& MyString::operator=(const MyString& str) {
    if (this != &str) {
        free(thestring);
        thestring = strdup(str.thestring);
    }
    return *this;
}

MyString::~MyString() {
    free(thestring);
}
```

Finally, I would rewrite your default constructor like this:

```
MyString::MyString()
:   thestring(0) {
}
```

Essentially, this is not different, but an initialization list is more canonical.

Comment: +1. Small note: for op assignment, i think we should check for self-assignment `if (this != &str)`

Comment: Why would the operator take a MyString argument, when i assign a value with quotations it will be receiving a constant char.

Comment: @DanielSega That assignment operator you need in addition to the one you have - it's part of the rule of three referenced in the answer. You also need your operator that assigns `const char *` - it should have a similar implementation to the one in the answer. Finally, you should also consider adding a constructor that takes a `const char*`.

Answer (score 1):

Line 9: `ms` is a `MyString*`, but `str` is just a `const MyString&` (ie, not a pointer).

Line 14: You cannot assign a `const char*` value to a `char*`, as this would potentially allow you to change it:

```
void foo(const char* dont_change_this) {
  char* s = dont_change_this;
  s[0] = '!';  // you changed it!
}
```

Line 15: Once again, a simple pointer mis-match. The return type of op= is `MyString&`, but `temp` has type `MyString*`.

Comment: Ok, i see it now. But how is MyString* any different from a MyString& since both contains a address?

Comment: @DanielSega `MyString*` and `MyString&` are completely different -- the latter is a [_reference type_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C++)). You are likely getting confused over the use of `&` as both the unary address-of operator and to denote reference types -- these are different and mostly unrelated uses of `&`.

Answer (score 0):

But you're not just trying to copy the data, you're trying to strip it of its constness. In other words, you're attempting to assign a non-const pointer with a const pointer. This would give you the ability to potentially change the value of what you intended to be "const".